# No valid bitrates : Error -5 in Roku player

Tags: media, http-live-streaming, playback, roku, brightscript

I get a -5 error in roku player saying "no valid bitrates" at times while playing a hls stream.

Tried debugging the segments, and they were a bit laggy when played in the browser, but they never showed up on Roku.

Comment: I think no one will be able to provide help without further details on the stream. Can you provide the stream and/or the content of the master playlist file?

Answer (score 0):

From recent experience with the same error, it seems to be due to a poor internet connection between the client and host, or other network related problems to the Roku.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was able to fix this error from OBS Studio, which is the software I use to stream, I changed the encoder, by default it was **x264**, I changed it to **Apple VT H264 software encoder**, and that solved the problem I had on Roku from "invalid bitrates" error.
It should be noted that the encoder differs according to the operating system, it is only a matter of testing each one of them.
As a description, I use **OBS Studio** as streaming software, **MediaCP** as distribution software.